# Vehicle Tracking in real time using EmguCV

Tags: emgucv

Briefly, I'm developing a system that detect and track cars in real time using EmguCV, so far the detection works fine, I've used Haar Cascade and a decent classifier to detect the vehicles but the problem lies in the tracking algorithm to be used.

After 3 days of continuous research I've concluded that 
1- Blob tracking and Background subtraction are the best to eliminate false positives in each frame and increase tracking accuracy
2- I can't find any good documentation for camshift/blob tracking at all

my c# skills aren't "that good" so I'm having it really hard to build the tracker myself

I can't seem to get [Vehicle Detection, Tracking and Counting](https://www.behance.net/gallery/Vehicle-Detection-Tracking-and-Counting/4057777) to work

Thanks in advance! :)